# How can I get final output states inside flow?

Tags: corda

At the end of a transaction flow, if it creates a new state (or states), how can I get access to the output StateAndRef objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do three things:

1. On your `SignedTransaction` object you can call `SignedTransaction.tx.outRefsOfType<T>()` and that will return a `List<StateAndRef<T>>` for you.
2. Perform a vault query to extract the states which have just been added to the vault. Vault queries return `List<StateAndRef<T>>`
3. Subscribe to an observable via the `trackBy` functionality of the vault. When the transaction is committed the observable will emit `StateAndRef<T>`s for the newly committed states